# suppress RPM install warning: "warning: group pulse does not exist - using root"

Tags: rpm, yocto

I'm using a yocto recipe to create an RPM from a tar.gz archive. However, when I try to install the package on my system (while booted from an external media) I get the following warning and a return code 1:

```
root@system:~# rpm -ivh --root=/mnt/media package.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
 1:package     warning: group pulse does not exist - using root
warning: group pulse does not exist - using root
warning: group pulse does not exist - using root
.
.
########################################### [100%]
.
warning: group pulse does not exist - using root
root@system:~# echo $?
1
```

The package seems to install fine when I'm booted from the on board storage, although it still shows the warning about the user group.

I've checked the source archive, my build system and yocto configuration files but haven't seen any trace of the user group pulse anywhere.
When I run `rpm -qplv package.rpm`, I do see the almost all files being owned by user group "pulse", but I'm not sure where it's coming from and how to get rid of it.

Is there a way to resolve this warning?
Any guidance is really appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get rid of this warning:

1. repackage the rpm such that the files belong to another user and group than *pulse*
2. create the *pulse* user and group before installing the package

There is no way to change an existing package unless repackaging yourself...

Comment: thanks for responding, the RPM is compiled by the yocto build system automatically and I don't see any traces of the user group "pulse", the source archive doesn't have it either. I've tried creating the pulse user group, but it still throws those warnings.

Comment: You need to create both user and group